# Logistic Regression Pattern in Deviance Variance Across Variables

Tags: logistic, modeling, deviance, churn

I fitted a Logistic Regression model for a Customer Churn dataset with the following results

[image: Logit Results]

I tested this model with a validation set and calculated the ROC AUC score, which was approximately 0.85 – quite good. However, I still need to look into the deviance, which was calculated in the following way:

```r
deviance_residuals = -2 * ((y_test * np.log(y_pred)) + 
    ((1 - y_test) * np.log(1 - y_pred)))
```

Now, looking at the deviance I noticed some weird patterns in two specific variables:

As shown in the scatterplot below, I could almost fit a linear regression between 'Tenure' for churners and its deviance.

[image: Tenure vs Deviance Scatterplot]

This makes me suspect that I might be missing something. I attempted applying log transformations to the tenure variable, but it didn't improve the situation. I also tried incluiding interactions of this variable and still didn't work

[image: Contract Type vs Deviance Boxplot]

Has anyone gone through something similar when fitting logistic regressions? I would appreciate your help!